# Статус бар android

Tags: java, android

В чем может быть проблема. Статус бар не меняет цвет. Т.е. почему здесь статус бар серый, а не поменялся в картинку, как должно быть в материал дизайне?

[image]

А вот здесь все нормально

[image]

вот xml первого скриншота

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/fon"
android:scaleType="centerCrop">


 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:text="@string/login"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/main"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

И соответственно тема:

```
<resources>

   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/main</item>
   </style>

    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">   </style>

</resources>
```

И еще 1 вопрос, можно ли как нибудь закруглить края кнопки?

Comment: [Как закруглить края кнопки](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=android%20button%20round%20corner&lr=62). Если хотите ответ здесь - задавайте новый вопрос. Дело в том, что в одном вопросе должна быть только одна проблема.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если в первом скринщоте используется второй стиль, то попробуйте добавить туда атрибуты из первого стиля.
За цвет статус бара отвечает

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
```

---

Чтобы статусбар прозрачным сделать надо с API 19 добавить в стиль атрибут

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

---

Чтобы разметка влезала под статус бар, он должен быть прозрачным, а размекта должна иметь атрибут

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```